# Autohotkeys: Wait till the previous command is executed fully

Tags: autohotkey

What I am trying to do here is open an Excel sheet and do some copy paste here and there. I have created a script which will open the file and then start operations on it. Now I am using a slow computer so it takes time for excel file to open. Is it possible to somehow tell my autohotkey script that the file is opened and now u can start your shit. I know I can do it with sleep function but I was wondering if there is something better.

Comment: @Anthon, do you know a `sleep` command in VBA?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would first check if Excel is running, then check if the specific file has been opened.

```
SetTitleMatchMode, 2

IfWinActive, Microsoft Excel
{
    WinGetTitle, title, A
    IfInString, title, specific file
    {
        Sleep, 1000 ; Just in case....


    }
}
```

Actually, you are better of with a WinWait, specific file